# Ссылки на вопросы/ответы

Tags: дефект, предложение, ссылки

При копировании ссылок на вопросы/ответы из адресной строки в комментарии/сообщения они выглядят страшно громоздкими, пример:

> _https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597614/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b2-html-js-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd

Хотя хвост из кодированных русских букв не несет ни какого смысла для точного определения страницы на которую ведет ссылка. Ссылку выше можно сократить до

> _https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597614/

Если вы перейдете по этой ссылке и попробуете открыть ссылку из первого комментария

> Возможный дубликат вопроса: [помогите написать программу которая открывая страницу html начинала пойти время с 00:00:00 что бы они запустились при открытии страницы до 24:59](ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597590/…

вас ждет ошибка сайта

```
Bad Request - Invalid URL

HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
```

а не страница с вопросом оригиналом. **Почему?** Да потому, что длинная ссылка не вошла в комментарий и была обрезана.

Предлагаю, чтобы движок сайта вырезал кодированные символы из ссылок (оставляя якоря ведущие на конкретные ответы на странице вопроса). Так он делает в тексте ссылки, которую видишь в комментарии (кроме якоря, видимо).

**UPD**
Возможно, длинные ссылки на вопросы/ответы следует автоматически менять на ссылки типа `поделиться` перед сохранением сообщения.

**UPD2**
Хм. Зря я наверное про `поделиться` дописал. Там же второе число это ссылка на юзера и получится накрутка счетчиков.

Comment: сейчас поищу дубликат: суть в том, что текст не нужен, можно его выкинуть до номера

Comment: По поводу ссылок есть [вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4078/176217). А вот дефекта ещё не было вроде бы такого.

Comment: Там вопрос :) , а у меня предложение, чтобы перед сохранением эта часть была вырезана из ссылок.

Comment: @Visman, на самом деле, есть специальная кнопка _поделиться_ для этого

Comment: Хотя да :-) не могу сразу прочитать весь вопрос :-)

Comment: @Grundy кнопка есть, но ссылка обрезалась системой автоматически при начале голосования по дублю, если я правильно понял.

Comment: Тогда ссылка которая была скопирована из адресной строки должна автоматически меняться на ссылку из `поделиться` ;)

Comment: @alexolut, ага, уже понял :)

Comment: @Visman, а вот тут - не должна :-) мало ли какая ссылка в адресной строке :)

Comment: @Grundy, пусть ИИ прикрутят для распознавания :)

Comment: _Там же второе число это ссылка на юзера и получится накрутка счетчиков._ - второе число не обязательно :) да и счетчик не особо что дает :)

Comment: @Grundy счетчик актуален для знаков типа [Публицист](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/61/publicist). Ещё никто не заработал кстати такого!

Comment: @alexolut, потому что у нас никто не делится :-)

Comment: @Grundy эй, ты, не кликай мою ссылку, понял! :) Но чуть более лайтовые знаки (60,59) уже есть, между прочим.

Comment: @alexolut, а делиться ссылками можно разве внутри ru.stackoverflow.com? Мне казалось, это только для внешних ресурсов?

Comment: @Visman а чего ж нельзя-то? Делитесь :) Только для знаков, я думаю, учитываются переходы только с внешних источников. Но вообще, хз. Из описания знака как-то не очень понятно.

Comment: Накрутки нет в рамках одного сайта, так что на сообщения при закрытии как дубликат это не повлияет.

Comment: По сути вопроса: эта строка полезна тем, что позволяет узнать заголовок вопроса до открытия ссылки. Что насчет транслита? (Кстати, недавно уже обсуждали это).

Comment: @NickVolynkin, информацию по цели ссылки можно добавить во всплывающее сообщение/окошко, как это сейчас происходит при наведении мыши на ник пользователя, например, а ссылки урезать.

Comment: @Visman с всплывающими сообщениями тоже [далеко не всё гладко](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287563/339911).

Comment: связанный вопрос: [discourage url shorteners in comments: don't add link's href size to the total comment size](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267293/137096)

Comment: Я уже давно привык копировать ссылку "поделиться" и вставлять именно её, потому что та длииииинная и то в лимит символов в комментариях упрёшься, то в лимит символов сообщения в чате. Также могу сказать, что в некоторых случаях (в чате точно) ссылки могут восстанавливаться из краткой формы поделиться обратно в длинную (если кидать только линк).

Comment: И мне кажется, что при расчёте знаков типа публицист не учитываются переходы по ссылкам на самом so -- только с внешних доменов. Иначе бы я уже давно в публицистах ходил, а так даже Диктора нету. Это надо проверять, примерно так, как это делали на прошлогоднем Winter Bash 2016. ([тынц](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4405/213987)) Никто не хочет через тор 25 раз покликать? )