# Какие соц. сети учитываются для получения шапки Amped Up?

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Из [описания](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/amped-up):

> **Amped Up** поделитесь ссылкой на вопрос через соц. сети, которая наберет
>   5 переходов

Будет ли учитываться, например вконтакт? Или речь идёт только о глобальных соц.сетях, известных в западном мире - скажем, только через facebook?

На многих сайтах кнопка "поделиться" содержит уже какой-то заранее предопределённый набор соц. сетей (пример - виджеты [я.share](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/) или [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/)), но в случае so ссылка просто является ссылкой на вопрос/ответ, поэтому не совсем понятно, что конкретно учитывается.

Или может там вообще неважно, какие соц. сети, просто достаточен сам факт перехода пять раз (скажем, с разных IP-адресов)?

Моя хакерская натура хочет провести два эксперимента: сначала зайти самому по ссылке с пяти разных IP-адресов (в моей конторе есть офисы на разных континентах) и кинуть ссылку во вконтактик в чат, где у меня знакомые по игре в мафию, там ещё больше разных людей перейдёт.

Вопрос только в том, как разделить эксперименты, чтобы не наложилось.

И вообще: если я кину ссылку на вопрос, который задал другой участник -- то кому засчитается шапка: тому кто поделился или тому, чей вопрос? Подозреваю, что тому, кто задал вопрос: в ссылке никакого параметра, указывающего на профиль поделившегося нет! )) Никто не хочет принять участие в эксперименте?

Comment: да черт его знает..... ребята из чата http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50144/ye-olde-hat-shoppe  говорят, что вообще достаточно ссылки на вопрос типа такой `http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4405` и всё. Любому дал - тот перешёл....... но я что-то в этом не уверен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалось получить **Amped Up** шляпу после открытия ссылки, полученной через кнопку "поделиться". Для этого при помощи VPN сменил несколько стран :) Т.о. использовать соц-сети, или кликать ссылку, чтобы был не пустой referer, вовсе не обязательно.

> [image: AmpedUp]

Comment: Подтверждаю. Открыл через Tor Browser ссылки пять раз (закрыть-открыть браузер - меняет IP-адрес) и получил шапку себе и тестовому пользователю -- [Елене](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212421/elena).

Comment: Халявная шапка, короче, но было интересно подумать в процессе получения, поэкспериментировать.

Comment: @AK тестовый пользователь знает, что он тестовый? :)

Comment: @alexolut а зачем. потом захочешь подкатить и скажет: а знаешь кто тебе шапку-магнитофон подарил? ))

Answer (score 3):

Шапка тому, кто поделится:

При нажатии кнопки поделиться ссылка имеет вид

```
http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/{id вопроса}/{id пользователя}
```

Поэтому вполне четко определяется - кто делился

Кроме того поделиться можно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Судя по всему соц-сетями считаются Google+, Twitter, Facebook

Comment: Вот только с соц. сети прилетает еще гет параметр. Например с фейсбука `?sfb=1` да и вообще может быть там запрос, является ли тот перешедший юзер пользователем указанной соц. сети. и если нет - то не начислять count++.

Comment: Логично, я невнимательно смотрел. Думал идентификатор вопроса слеш индетификатор ответа. Щас тогда я попробую наколдовать шапок ))

Comment: Судя по [ответу](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288374/339911) совершенно не важно, где размещать ссылку. Главное, чтобы юзеры с разными IP по ней пришли. Давайте в чате накидаем таких ссылок друг другу и проверим :)

Answer (score 1):

Получил эту шапку, не публикуя ссылки нигде, кроме нашего чата. Похоже, чат тоже считается соцсетью.

Предполагаю, что условия те же, что со знаками:

- нужно использовать рефссылку
- нужно открыть её любым способом
- реферер (если есть) должен быть не тем же сайтом SE, на который ведет ссылка
- если ссылка открывается залогиненным пользователем, любое количество посещений считается за одно
- аналогично, открытия с разных IP в одном браузере будут объединены с помощью cookies

Сомневаюсь, что разработчики стали бы ради этой шляпы создавать список соцсетей. Их слишком много. И были бы пользователи, которые честно опубликовали ссылку в местной соцсети какой-нибудь страны, а им ничего не дали.

Comment: Проверено на Елене: пять пустых реферреров отлично срабатывают, так что его похоже просто не учитывают. Вообще.

Comment: @AK а пробовали, чтобы в реферере был ru.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Никаких объединений с помощью куки не было. Открывал всё в одной вкладке. Просто менял VPN.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не-а, смысла уже не видел.