# Автокомментарий о дубликате превысил допустимую длину комментария и сломался

Tags: дефект, комментарии, дубликаты, ссылки, шаблонные-комментарии

Отмечая [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/747099/181100) как дубликат [другого вопроса о, предположительно, том же самом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478100/181100), я обнаружил, что оставленный автоматически комментарий превысил допустимую длину и внезапно оборвался, сломав разметку ссылки:

```
Возможный дубликат вопроса: [вопрос](длиннющая-ссылка-с-экранированной-кирилли
```

Завершающая круглая скобка отвалилась.

Комментарий я исправил, пока была возможность, заменив экранированный заголовок вопроса внутри ссылки на коротенькую заглушку, но проблема, тем не менее, имеет место.

---

*(На английский нужно переводить?)*

Comment: Этот вопрос уже раза три фигурировал на мете) Минимум в июле https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5585/191482 ? максимум - год назад https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4148/191482

Comment: @АлексейШиманский забавно, поиском сходу не обнаружил. Задубликатил к последнему.

Comment: Так можно несколько выбрать дубликатов. Правда нужно золото по метке или ромб. Переводить не надо, ибо [вот](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303001/339911).

Comment: @alexolut Вроде бы получилось!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хорошо вам.